# How to stop scrollViewer at that position and draw

Tags: windows-phone-7

In xaml, I have the following:

ScrollViewer Name="Scv" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="150,194,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto"

Canvas Height="100" Name="canvas1" Width="424"

Image Canvas.Left="7" Canvas.Top="10" Height="150" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" Width="200" ManipulationStarted="image1_ManipulationStarted"

InkPresenter Name="inkPresenter1" 
  inkPresenter1>

Canvas
  ScrollViewer

The problem :

How to stop the ScrollViwer at the position where I stop scrolling as I need to draw something on the photo at that position?

If I use a button to stop it, it always return to the Top position even I have scrolled at the bottom

when click button to stop

Scv.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;
 Scv.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Disabled;

To resume scrolling after stop

Scv.VerticalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;
  Scv.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility = ScrollBarVisibility.Visible;

Answer (score 0):

Given that `sc` is the name of the `ScrollViewer` control, you can set the current scrolling offset to the actual one and it will stop scrolling. Like this:

```
sc.ScrollToVerticalOffset(sc.VerticalOffset);
```

If you decide to scroll it horizontally, the same idea applies.

Comment: It is possible to make the ScrollViewer Complete Stop ? Yr solution is good but If I start to draw up or down using Finger, the scrollViewer will follow up or down making drawing difficult. Thanks